# Matrix pricing structure for ubercart?

Tags: ubercart

We sell hosting and domain name registrations. My problem is with the hosting where you have, for example: "Shared Hosting" with Package A and Package B. Prices are as follows:

```
|           | Package A | Package B
| 3 months  | 5 USD     | 15USD
| 6 months  | 8 USD     | 20USD
| 12 months | 14 USD    | 30USD
```

Now, I can add two attributes, one for "package type" and another for "period". So you can choose, for example, package A for 6 months. The problem is, ubercart doesnt quite work like that. It would ADD an amount, depending on what you choose, when I need fixed pricing for a specific combination. Woocommerce does this beautifully.

How do I do it with Ubercart and Drupal 7?

Comment: So you don't need recurring billing, but instead you need fixed pricing for a given period that you will set, that will be billed all at once, correct?

Comment: exactly. that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, I'd recommend doing "Shared Hosting - Package A" as one product, and "Shared Hosting - Package B" as another, rather than a single product called "Shared Hosting" that has two attributes. (You can add the time period as a single attribute to each product.)

You can still style the matrix as you have done above (on a pricing page) and include links to purchase at the bottom of the column for each package.

Comment: I think this is the right approach. Two separate products both with one attribute for 'period'. If you use https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_field_attribute you can reuse the field 'period' for both products and change the instance and therefore the cost.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Ubercart Price List](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_pricelist) module

[image]

> Ubercart Price List this allows the site administrator to create
>   multiple instances of price-lists and assign those to certain roles in
>   the system. A good example is if you sell a number of products whose
>   price changes based on quantity, but you would like to have different
>   lists for different roles on the site.